# I need Virtual Memory usage in Win32 sample

Tags: c++, virtual-memory

I need little simple application for working with virtual memory in WIN32. Something like in Jeffrey Richter. Maybe anyone can share with me useful links? (for example working with big arrays) Google didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Catch22](http://catch22.net/tuts/bigmem01) has good tutorials on memory management.

Comment: I noticed that here are being used memory-mapped-files but I need use virtual memory to work with Big Arrays. Sorry for early confusing in the question.I recreated topic for this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279197/sample-of-virtual-memory-using-to-work-with-big-arrays

Comment: virtual memory really is a memory mapped file. If you want the OS to handle it for you, it does that automatically.